# Setting up throttleTime() operator correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a button whose click event handler is set to a function: `<button (click)="someFunction(test1)">get stuff</button>`

`someFunction()` does some stuff but then it calls a service function that does a http get.

```
 this._myService.getDetails(username).pipe(
      throttleTime(10000)
).subscribe()
```

In my service:

```
  getDetails(username: string) {
    return this._http.get(url);
  }
```

This obviously won't work because every time I click the button a new http get call is issued.

What would be a good way of setting up a throttleTime()-like functionality where http get calls are issued after a certain time out length?

Comment: Do you want to do an http call every time you click the button or do you want to debounce them?

Comment: I want the clicks not to do a http get if with in a certain time frame.  If set to 3 seconds, for example, and if the button is clicked multiple times within the three seconds I want just the first one to go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need a `throttleTime` (see the comparative marble diagram below)

Yet currently you're throttling the **response stream**, instead you need to throttle your **button click stream**.

To do so, we can create a stream out of button clicks:

```tsx
<button (click)="someFunction(test1)">get stuff</button>
```

```tsx
class Component {
  btnClickSubject$ = new Subject<void>();
  someFunction(){
    this.btnClickSubject$.next(void 0);
  }
}
```

And then `*Map` it to the http-get request:

```tsx
class Component {
  //...

  destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.btnClickSubject$.pipe(
      // throttle clicks
      throttleTime(3000),

      // switchMap or other *Map operator to switch to http-get
      switchMap(() => this._http.get('url')),

      // complete with component destroy *
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    )
    .subscribe(response => console.log(response))
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(void 0);
  }

}
```

* Note that we need explicitly tell this subscription to complete with component "onDestroy"

--

And heres a comparison of **[debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/debounceTime-vs-throttleTime-vs-auditTime-vs-sampleTime/)**

[image: debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) operator.

> debounceTime delays values emitted by the source Observable, but drops
>   previous pending delayed emissions if a new value arrives on the
>   source Observable. This operator keeps track of the most recent value
>   from the source Observable, and emits that only when dueTime enough
>   time has passed without any other value appearing on the source
>   Observable. If a new value appears before dueTime silence occurs, the
>   previous value will be dropped and will not be emitted on the output
>   Observable.

See an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ahyzry?file=index.ts).

The official RxJS docs are [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime).

Comment: I believe my setup is wrong somewhere.  It's acting almost like every button click is a new subscription so the rxjs operators seem to do not do anything at all (regardless or if its debounceTime or throttleTime)