# Angular app, using throttletime to cap api calls. Using state to keep track of calls with different parameters

Tags: angular, api, rxjs, throttling

I want to be able to throttle my api calls on a service level in Angular 10.
All answers and all example I find on the use of rxjs throttleTime describes scenarios where we have a user interaction that triggers the throttling. Like the following SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948393/setting-up-throttletime-operator-correctly/55951918)

But in my case the user and components can trigger the same service code to load data, from different places in the app.
So when the user navigates to a page they will trigger the call and then when they use a drop down they would trigger it again etc.
It is an expensive call, but I still need to keep it relatively fresh. I would like to achieve this by automatically having it refresh everytime the user interacts with it but having a 10 second pause  between every refresh.

The api endpoint can be called with different values. So `endpoint/1` will return a different value than `endpoint/2`
Meaning a flat non aware throttle would leave people with the wrong data for 10 seconds, before it was allowed to call the api again and refresh the viewstate.
Which in turn would add to the complexity of the throttle code I would have to create everywhere in my App.

So I thought that I could centralize the throttling to the service, instead of implementing throttleling code like the SO posts example.

But at this point I have hit a wall for my rxjs/angular skills, and my mind is turning to impossible.

What I tried to do was to have a dictionary on the service that was indexed based on the parameter given to the api, which would then be able to return an observable that the component could subscribe to.
Which would lead to the service having a dictionary with a "state" per parameter option.

The code is taken out of some context and stuff has been renamed.

```js
class demoState {
  triggerSubject$: Subject<void>;
  callApi$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(callApiObservable: Observable<any>) {
    this.triggerSubject$ = new Subject<void>();

    this.callApi$ = this.triggerSubject$.pipe(
      throttleTime(1000),
      switchMap(_ => callApiObservable)
    );
  }

  getRessourceUsingTrigger(): Observable<any> {
    // this is the first time I get "stumbed" I don't know a good way to delay the trigger 
    // of the subject until the end component subscribes.
    return of(0).pipe(
      // this will trigger before the switchmap is hit and therefore it goes into the void
      map(_ => this.triggerSubject$.next(void 0)),
      // so this doesn't matter because its underlying observable it never triggered.
      switchMap(_ => this.callApi$)
    );
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThrottleService {
  private testEndpointTrigger: { [testId: number]: demoState } = {};
  constructor() { }

  getFromTest(testId: number): Observable<any> {
    if(this.testEndpointTrigger[testId] === undefined){
      this.testEndpointTrigger[testId] = new demoState(this.GetFromAPI(testId));
    }
    return this.testEndpointTrigger[testId].getRessourceUsingTrigger();
  }

  private GetFromAPI(test: number): Observable<any> {
    return of(test);
  }

}

@Component({
  ...
})
export class PasswordChangeComponent  {

  constructor(private throttleService: ThrottleService){}

   usingServiceOnUserButtonClick(testId: number){
    this.throttleService.getFromTest(testId).subscribe(o => {
      console.log('do stuff with the values ', o);
    });
  }
}
```

I am hoping you could help me realise what I am doing wrong, or help me in a different direction towards achieving this goal.

---

Edit after first comment by bryan60.
I will try to take a step back rephrase it a bit an go from there.

I have an api call from my angular app that is expensive. I is located in "Service1". I want it to not be called whenever the user navigates(the component calls it in oninit) or when the user interact with the ui.
The data is used on different pages in the app, and could be used to populate dropdowns, but it change enough for me to want it relatively fresh(update every 10 seconds upon interaction).

The ApiCall will generate different results depending on user inputs.
So when we navigate to a page the default parameter would be `myapi/endpoint/1`, and the user can then change that and we would call `myapi/endpoint/2`.
At this point it needs to ignore the 10 seconds "throttle", because we need to fetch data that wasn't previously present in the app.
If the user were to swap back to the value that triggered `.../1` before 10 seconds was up, we would need to not call the api, and show some cached data.

The code I showed that is wrong, did not attempt to capture the "cached" aspect of the equation seing as that I wanted the throtteling to work first.

The Service needs to "rate limit" based on inputs given. I want it in the service and not the caller, to avoid having the throttle logic in each component.
My thought being that the component would need to have access to some sort of history of which api parameters that was previously sent.

I looked around rxjs and thought to myself throttletime sounds like a good soloution for this, but I have been unable to find an example that doesn't have a straight user interaction for every triggered event. Like autocomplete or button clicks.

Comment: this is a little in the weeds, can you step back a little and try to just give some requirements for this throttle service that you're trying to achieve

Comment: Ah okay, I have tried to add some text at the end, to try and elaborate on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

## A Possible Solution

#### priorityThrottleTime

Here's a custom operator that lets you throttle based on values on a key. That means whatever type of stream you have, you need to map(transform) it into the right shape before using this operator.

This is the required shape (Note that the key 'priority' can be changed from its default).

```html
{
  ...payload,
  priority: string
}
```

If this operator sees any values without the required shape, they get throttled under a `default` category and `priorityThrottleTime` behaves like regular `throttleTime` for those values.

You can set the default string to ensure it doesn't clash with your priority strings.

```ts
function priorityThrottleTime<T>(
  thrTime: number,
  priorityStr = "priority",
  defaultStr = "default"
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return s => defer(() => {
    const priorityTimeStamp = new Map<string, number>();
    return s.pipe(
      filter(v => Date.now() - (
        priorityTimeStamp.get(v[priorityStr]) || 
        priorityTimeStamp.get(defaultStr) ||
        0) >= thrTime
      ),
      tap(v => priorityTimeStamp.set(
        v[priorityStr] || defaultStr, 
        Date.now())
      )
    );
  });
}
```

I haven't taken the time to test this thoroughly, so you'll want to try it out and iron out the kinks.

## An example

Here I take some strings, and throttle based on the first letter of each string.

```ts
from(["Hey", "Jude,", "don't",
  "make", "it", "bad", "take",
  "a", "sad", "song", "and",
  "make", "it", "Better"
]).pipe(
  // Map string into an object that 
  // priorityThrottleTime can use
  map(lyric => ({
    lyric,
    priority: lyric.substring(0, 1)
  })),
  priorityThrottleTime(1000),
  // Map back into a string
  map(({ lyric }) => lyric)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

If your emissions are already objects, you could give `priorityThrottleTime` a second argument that matches the key on those objects or use the technique above to generate a custom priority string.